# Excel sheet error in C#

Tags: c#

I want to write some data to excelsheet file from datatable, i write this code

```
    string path = "D:\\Project\\SMCCampaignmgmt\\trunk\\UserFolder\\NewFolder\\saran.xlsm";
    oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = false;
    oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
    oXL.UserControl = false;
    //error on this line
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Add();
    }
    else
    {


        mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
    }
    mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;

    //Get the allready exists sheet
    mWSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mWorkSheets.get_Item("Template");

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = mWSheet1.UsedRange;


    mWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
    Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
    false,false, Missing.Value,
    Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    mWorkBook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    mWSheet1 = null;

    mWorkBook = null;

    oXL.Quit();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
```

But am getting the error as Cannot access the file, because its readonly.
How i can get rid.

Comment: how to make it as writeable... am new to C#. brief advice will help me a lot.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#. The problem is that your user account has no write access to that file. You will have to change the user permissions on your file

Answer (score 1):

If the file already exists, you open it (to read), and then call `SaveAs()` with the same file. Probably you get the readonly error there (you didnt specify which line gave the error), because the file is already open and cannot be overwitten. Try writing to a different path.

Comment: This line gives me Error.                       mWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
    Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
    false,false, Missing.Value,
    Missing.Value, Missing.Value);